# How do I change the template of the Mailchimp Wordpress widget?

Tags: templates, wordpress, mailchimp

I want to change how the form looks like and the labels on the fields of the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login in as Admin and then, under the Plugins area in the sidebar, click Editor. There's a dropdown menu labeled "Select plugin to edit". Click that and select "MailChimp" and then click the "Select" button. The sidebar widget form is called `mailchimp/mailchimp_widget.php`

The form's code begins right after the first PHP block.

You can also edit the code directly by looking in the `wordpress/wp-content/plugins/mailchimp/` directory. The translations are in the `po` sub-directory.

The trick with this template is that the fields are loaded from elsewhere. In order to change the label, you have to set the option of the fields in the PHP code. Each field is looped through and printed out automatically.

For example to change the "Email Address" label to read "Email" add the following code at the end of the first PHP block:

```
$mv[0]['name'] = 'Email';
```

This assumes that the first field that will be printed out is the Email Address field. You can do a `var_dump` to see what other options are available.

*If you want to make more drastic changes to the form, remember that when the widget is updated, you'll have to make the changes again and merge them with the updated version.*